# How to use a custom USB device (WinUSB) on Microsoft HoloLens 2?

Tags: usb, hololens, winusb

I made a custom USB sensor device that runs on a Windows 8.1 / 10 desktop computer using the WinUSB driver (I implemented Microsoft extended USB descriptors in device firmware to automatically install the driver when the device connected).

Can I use a WinUSB device on HoloLens2? Or, if there is no WinUSB support on HoloLens2, how can I use my USB device with a “custom USB device class”?

At the moment, I do not have a hololens2, but I need to understand how the USB works on it.

Edit: I found this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-connect-devices#hololens-2-connect-usb-c-devices

It says that hololens2 supports the following device classes:

```
Mass storage devices (such as thumb drives)
Ethernet adapters (including ethernet plus charging)
USB-C-to-3.5mm digital audio adapters
USB-C digital audio headsets (including headset adapters plus charging)
Wired mouse
Wired keyboard
Combination PD hubs (USB A plus PD charging)
```

My device does not implement any of these classes (custom class). Is there a chance to make it work on hololens2?

Answer (score 1):

I finally tested my code and USB device on real Hololens 2. The USB device works great there because Hololens2 supports WinUSB! The WinUSB driver was installed automatically (my device has WinUSB descriptors).

Comment: May I ask what USB device you were using and what VID/PID you device had?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you referred, all classes HoloLens2 supports have been listed, and unlisted classes are not supported.
Could you provide more information about your business request and submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices?
If it’s a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule. Actually, the existing classed on HoloLens 2 are also based on user’s feedback in such way.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app)